# How to embed python -c multiline script in shell script function with input parameter

Tags: python, shell

I have a shell script function with 1 input parameter. Inside the function I am embedding the python multiline script which just prints value in python and export to shell variable.

I tried embedding the python script in direct shell script without putting it in a function and not passed any input parameter. The problem is on how to pass the shell variable to python script present in a function.

getValues(){
name=$1
echo $name
`python -c '
   import ..
   value=""
   for ..
     for key in ..
         if "${name}" in key.tags:
             value=str(key["tag"])
             break;
print(value)'`
}

export env=`getValues Environment`
export product=`getValues Product`

I expected the actual result like dev/stage (prints from value) but I am getting empty string in shell.

Anything am doing it wrong?

NOTE: I have used '`' as expr to call the shell expressions in code but its not printing in code section here.

Comment: Why not read it from a file?

Comment: This is like more like a generic function. I don't want to have IO request. Will call this shell function with different input parameters and export different shell variables. So one function export many shell variables with different input parameters.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no errors ... the python script alone when ran in python interpreter I am getting the expected result. When embedded in shell, I am getting empty string. Say when I did echo $env -> am getting empty value.

Comment: Please show the full `code` and the `file`(s) being used/read if any

Comment: I am not using any file. I am using AWS EMR Tags so at bootstrap, I will read the tags configured in EMR cluster and export it to the ec2 instances which am doing it in python embed in shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just ask the `python` to read from `stdin` like,

```
$ cat emb.bash
getvalues(){
    name="$1"
python - <<EOF
data = {'key': 'foo'}
x = [1,2,3,4,5,'$name']
for k in x:
    if k == data.get('key'):
        print(k)
    else:
        print('Nope')
EOF
}

getvalues foo
```

Output:

```
$ bash emb.bash
Nope
Nope
Nope
Nope
Nope
foo
```

Also, you should note there's a utility called `jq` [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) that will help you read json file.

Comment: @SRIRAMRAMACHANDRAN No problem. Glad to be able to help